# Embedded system, How to define or calculate a time period

Tags: algorithm, arduino, embedded, scheduled-tasks, scheduling

For designing embedded systems, one of the steps is scheduling.

I know the execution time can be measured by using some functions.  For example, I can use `micro()` in Arduino to measure the time between start time and end time.

But I have a question, how to define the period as known as deadline? I want my system to use Earliest Deadline First (EDF), Rate Monotonic Scheduling (RMS) or both.
How can I find out the correct number and proof that this system is schedulable? Giving a random number seems not a good way for designing, I think there should be a way to define or calculate a number for period.

(I have searched for this information for 1 hour, but I couldn't find any useful information. Any tips or comments are good for me.)

---

*update

so currently I am taking a class, embedded software systems. My professor asks us to simulate everything on the TinkerCAD by using Arduino. We have to create platooning trucks and implement part of the behavior based on this system. For example, there are three trucks traveling in a platoon, what will happen if the trucks encounter human, stop sign or animals? Maybe the leading truck sends a brake message to the following trucks, re-launch the engines then keep traveling in the platoon.

[image: EDF example]
Take an example from the book, we already know the execution time, and how can we know that now we should place 5 for task 1's period and place 7 for task 2's period? When people are designing a system, how do they know what number will be placed for the period?

So my question is, how can I know or calculate the number for the period maybe for braking, for re-launch the engines and for keep traveling in a platoon when I am designing a system?

Comment: Arduino is not a real time operating system, so you can't make timing guarantees unless you're using a significantly small amount of the system's total resources (processor time, CAN bus throughput, etc.). And if you're using such a small amount of the system resources, then using a scheduling algorithm seems like overkill - you've already guaranteed schedulability by sheer magnitude alone.

Comment: Can you clarify what tasks your system needs to be able to complete? What are it's inputs and outputs? Consider buttons, LEDs, transmitters, serial lines, gpios, etc.

Comment: You *can* analytically determine the time a process takes to complete one iteration, but you need to look at the machine code compiled by your compiler, and you need to understand how many clock cycles each of those operations may take. This is not possible if your system is in any way non-deterministic (has a cache, and you can't prove in what order the memory will be retrieved; the processor uses pipelining and branch prediction; etc.) so it's likely only possible and cost effective for extremely safety critical devices.

Comment: FWIW, system profiling is usually "good enough", especially if you're not stuck in 1982 and need to squeeze every clock cycle out of a processor. If you're more than 50% loaded on a resource, just buy the next more expensive chip.

Comment: @JohnFilleau yes, I know that arduino is not a real time operatin system. But our prof asks us to use arduino to simulate everything in the tinkercad.

Comment: @JohnFilleau we will use ultrasonic distance sensor, arduino uno and serial monitor. Since in the tinkercad, there is no way to use camera to recognize the image, we use serial monitor to represent the situations. For example, 1 means we encouter human, 2 means we encouter stop sign ... etc.

Comment: @JohnFilleau for the last two comments, maybe I have to take some time to realize what you said, will reply later. But thank you for your professional response!

Comment: This looks an analysis problem, not a programming one.

Comment: @JohnFilleau There's no reason why you can't have real-time calculations/guarantees on an AVR. You might have to throw the Arudino libs and C++ out though. It's easy enough to implement a "poor man's RTOS" by having a list of tasks, clock each task, optionally implement timeouts or watchdog windows etc. ->

Comment: AVR doesn't use cache or branch prediction, maybe pipelining (I don't remember) but if so, likely rather simplistic and deterministic. On low-end MCUs with pipelining you usually calculate for the worst case, which would be as many cycles as each instruction is specified to take - and if pipelining happens to improve that, it's just a bonus.

Answer (score 1):

The mathematics for EDF schedulability are described at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earliest_deadline_first_scheduling, and similarly for RMS at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate-monotonic_scheduling.  It is all rather theoretical and in the real world it is often more empirical.

> How can I find out the correct number...

It is not clear what "number" you are referring to, but if you mean how to calculate the "deadline" for a specific task, that is not really what the schedulability test yields.  Rather it determines given the maximum-execution time of a task whether or not all tasks will meet their deadlines.

The theoretical models also make a number of assumptions such as periodic tasks and negligible context switch overhead.  But event driven systems often have few or no periodic tasks.  Meeting response deadlines in the microsecond order does not lend itself to periodic scheduling.  In that case you must use both worst case execution time and worst case event rate.

Comment: yes, the period in my question means deadline. Thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a really broad question since there are multiple things you are asking about and references to multiple scheduling algorithms.  I can attempt to answer your first question:  you have to know something about how the system is being used and what its users expect in order to define what the deadline or desired period is for a particular task.

For example, for the task of monitoring the state of a pushbutton that is pressed by a human finger, it's probably fine to monitor it once every 10 ms (100 times per second), because humans cannot press or unpress a button very quickly.

I don't know about those fancy scheduling algorithms you are referring to, but for many applications it is sufficient to just handle each task in your main loop, and then try to design your main loop so an iteration always completes within a few milliseconds.

Unfortunately, I don't know how to prove that the main loop will run in a specific time.  It seems like that *should* be the job of your compiler to help you prove that, but I don't know of any popular embedded compilers that even attempt to do that.  So the best we can do in practice is measure the run time.

For any tasks that need to run quickly or run more often than the main loop, consider using interrupts, and setting the interrupt priority levels carefully (if your system supports that).

Comment: I will try to understand what you said. Thank you for your response, it's helpful!

Comment: @TaiwaneseFoodIsTheBest. Ok.  My point is that you don't calculate the deadline. The deadline (or period for a periodic task) is determined by the needs of the application. For example; _how quickly do the brakes need to be applied to avoid a collision?_.  Then you _measure_ or determine the execution time of the task, then apply these two values for each task to the schedulability test.